# size of remote file is not known of the fetch run time

Tags: unix, command-line, fetch

When I carried out a fetch command, the following messages were output.

"size of remote file is not known"

Will this be an error? Will it be what or the thing which disappears if I appoint an option? Or will it be all right even if I do not mind it?

Comment: What "fetch" command are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Freebsd fetch](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/fetch.1.html) command, right?

That is not an error, just a warning. I don't think there's an option to suppress that warning, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the HTTP server doesn't send the Content-Length header with the response. That way, the client doesn't know in advance how long the file is, and has to assume that it ends when the connection is closed by the server, with the side effect that if the connection drops prematurely, you'll end up with an incomplete download without knowing it.

This doesn't sound very good, but is in fact quite usual practice on the web, especially for dynamic content generated by scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way in UNIX
//File size of Google Image 
echo "Weberdev Logo Size : " . getRemoteFileSize'http://www.weberdev.com/images/BlueLogo150x45.gif');

Comment: Your answer is fairly nonsensical, I assume it was eaten on submission, right?